# How to handle caret + character options in GNU nano editor in Ubuntu

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, nano

Extremely simple question. In the attached image the majority of options seem to entail typing `^` and another character at the same time. The problem is that to type `^` I need to press `Shift + 6`, at which point I am actually typing `^` before I have a chance to press the second character, e.g. `^T`.

[image]

Comment: In this context, `^` should be interpreted as the Ctrl key. See for example [Why is the circumflex/caret character used as a symbol for Ctrl?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/265245/why-is-the-circumflex-caret-character-used-as-a-symbol-for-ctrl)

Comment: ... see also [Terminal Question: Been trying to escape this screen with "^X + Enter" but it doesnt work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1325862/terminal-question-been-trying-to-escape-this-screen-with-x-enter-but-it-do)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`^O` is a representation of a *character*, the one usually sent by your terminal upon pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>, not a key. In terminals, applications get input by reading a stream of bytes from a `/dev/tty*` or `/dev/pt*` device file, not by handling keyboard events, and those bytes are the  ones that are sent there by  your terminal when you press some key or key combination.

With an ASCII-based terminal as used on ASCII based systems (the norm these days though most systems/terminals extend it to support non-American-English characters), when you type <kbd>a</kbd> to <kbd>z</kbd>, the terminal sends byte 97 to 122 (or `0x60 | letter`), the ones representing the `a` to `z` characters in ASCII; if you do the same whilst holding the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key, they send bytes 65 to 90 (`0x40 | letter`), `A` to `Z` in ASCII.

With <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, they send bytes 1 to 26 (`0x00 | letter`¹).

Now, bytes 0 to 31 are *control* characters, they don't have glyphs, font representations. They have names (see `man ascii`). Like 9 (as sent upon <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> or <kbd>⭾</kbd>) is tab, 10 is newline (sent upon <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd>), 13 is carriage-return (sent upon <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd>, though beware the terminal driver often translates it to a newline).

The character sent upon <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> is the *shift-in* control character. If `nano` had `<shift-in> Write Out` instead of `^O Write Out`, I'd bet most people wouldn't know how to send that control character.

`^A` ... `^Z` (and `^[` `^\` `^]` `^^` `^_` for 27..31, and `^@` for 0, `^?` for 127¹) sometimes called *hat notation* are common visual representations of those characters. You'll find that it's also the one used by `cat -vt` or by the terminal line discipline after `stty echoctl`.

Other notations include `\CA` or `\C-A`. Some control characters have representations in C strings such as `\n` for `^J`/newline, `\a` for `^G`/BEL.

But the `^A` / `\C-A` ones are more useful to indicate how you can generate them with a keyboard.

---

<sup>¹ `@` being 0x40 in ASCII and `?` 0x3f, so the `^X` character is  rather obtained with `0x40 ^ X`, that is the byte value of X with the second most significant bit flipped. You'll also find the `M-^X` and `M-X` representation for bytes 0x80 to 0x9f and 0xa0 to 0xff which ASCII-only terminals used to send upon <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> and <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, though nowadays they rather send ESC (`^[`) followed by `^X`/`X` as the 8th bit is used instead for non-ASCII characters and I'd expect `nano` these days to expect `^[U` rather than byte 0xd5 to mean `M-U Undo` as that byte 0xd5 is also found as the first byte of the UTF-8 encoding of Armenian characters U+0540 to U+057F or is `Õ` in ISO8859-1 (aka latin1)</sup>